# How to resolve jquery auto complete issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Autocomplete is not working using jquery.I tried but not working. Autocomplete values is coming from json.If i type some words then related words should be display like dropdown but not working.I am not able to find the mistake from my code.Anyone can resolve this issue?

https://jsfiddle.net/583seq1h/2/

```
$("#suggest").autocomplete({
        delay: 10,
        source: function (request, response) {

            // Suggest URL
            var suggestURL = "http://testingurl.com/complete/search.htm";

            // JSONP Request
            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                url: suggestURL
            })
            .success(function(data){
                response(data[1]);
            });
        }
  });
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="type something ..." id="suggest" />
```

search.htm:

```
{


"results":[ 

{

"name":"Japan",
"type":"suggest"

},
{

"name":"Malesiya",
"type":"suggest"

},
{

"name":"China",
"type":"suggest"

},
{

"name":"USA",
"type":"suggest"

},
{

"name":"canada",
"type":"suggest"

}


] 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a non-existant web address in use.

```
var suggestURL = "http://testing.com/complete/search.json";
```

The json you have linked in this variable does not exist (redirects to a chinese 404).

```
var suggestURL = "http://suggestqueries.com/complete/search.json";
```

Additionally the json file you have linked in your post also does not exist (domain has not been renewed)

Also, you will get a "Blocked loading mixed active content" error whilst testing in jsfiddle, so you may want to consider testing your code by a different method.

[image: Error log]

Comment: testing.com is my secret web blog so no problem

Comment: It still leads to a 404 for me

Comment: And anyways, check my edit at the bottom of my post

Comment: You might be better off actually uploading your code to your website and just manually testing it there the old fashioned way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `return` data after `success`:

```
$("#suggest").autocomplete({
        delay: 10,
        source: function (request, response) {

            // Suggest URL
            var suggestURL = "http://suggestqueries.com/complete/search.json";

            // JSONP Request
            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                url: suggestURL
            })
            .success(function(data){
                return response(data[1]);
            });
        }
  });
```

Comment: How to use .htm file in ajax?

Comment: You can use `.xml` or `.json` only

Comment: Any other way is there? Because I can not change extension